# Update multiple rows in one table with differing values from another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following 3 tables. The 1st table has about 100 rows. How can I update the CompanyId in the first table with its corresponding value from the 3rd table via one update statement?

```
T1
-----------------------------
FileId | CompanyId
-----------------------------
ABC      | NULL  
DEF      | NULL

T2
-----------------------------
FileId  | UserId
-----------------------------
ABC       | 123  
DEF       | 456

T3
-----------------------------
UserId  | CompanyId
-----------------------------
123       | V1  
456       | V2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this statement:

```
UPDATE T1
SET COMPAYID = T3.CompanyId
FROM T1 INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.FILEID = T2.FILEID
        INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.USERID = T3.USERID
```